# Change in performance with fetch first row clause

Tags: oracle, performance

I have a complicated query for payroll calculation.
The result of query will be bulk collected in a TYPE and returned by my function.
count of result is about 29000 rows;
this query consume long time to retrieve (above 10 minutes);
but when I add

> fetch first 10000000 row only

at the bottom of my query, the result will be returned in few seconds;
Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Possibly caching, though this sounds extreme - is this repeatable if you add and remove that row limiting clause? Look at the execution plans for both versions. Possibly one is based on old statistics and the other on fresh ones.

Comment: The addition of a count stop like that will change Oracle's execution plan, perhaps in unexpected ways. The explanation for the change in performance will be in the altered plan, not in the fetch first clause itself. Any change to a SQL of any nature can cause a totally different plan to be used and radically change performance. You have to look at the plan, figure out what was wrong, and address it surgically for the exact SQL you intend to actually use.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes this is repeatable . I will check the plan.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch first N rows only` can make oracle prefer a first rows plan. The optimizer will optimize for a query that returns the first rows faster, even if it means the last rows will take much longer.

If you compare the two plans I suspect that the fetch first query will have a much higher cost, meaning that oracle thinks it will take longer even though it doesn't